# Why string is a reference type, but behaves differently from other reference types?

Tags: c#, string

We know that string is a reference type , so we have

```
string s="God is great!";
```

but on the same note if i declare class say Employee which is a reference type so why below piece of code does not work ?

```
Employee e = "Saurabh";
```

2- How do we actually determine if a type is a reference type or value type?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That code would work if you had an implicit conversion from a string to an `Employee`. Basically a string literal is of type `string` - i.e. its value is a string reference (and an interned one at that). You can only assign a value of one type to a variable of another type if there's a conversion between the two types - either user-defined or built in. In this case, there's no conversion from `string` to `Employee`, hence the error.

Contrary to some other answers, the types don't have to be the *same* - for example, this is fine:

```
object x = "string literal";
```

That's fine because there's an implicit reference conversion from `string` to `object`. Likewise you can write:

```
XNamespace ns = "some namespace";
```

because there's an [implicit conversion from string to `XNamespace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace.op_implicit.aspx).

To answer your second question: to see if a type in .NET is a value type or a reference type... `struct` and `enum` types are value types; everything else (class, delegate, interface, array) is a reference type. That's excluding pointer types, which are a bit different :)

Comment: +1 Excellent example of implicit conversion with `XNamespace`.

Comment: Good explanation .. and i got rejected due to this question , it was really embrassing for me to not answering this basic question , i screwed up !!!

Comment: I find it hard to believe that microsoft is asking such simple questions (although they are tricky).  But this is nothing compared to the google interview.

Comment: that's true but sometime basics are important and many people lack in basics like i did :(

Comment: @Marek: See saurabh's first comment.

Comment: @Jon sorry, I somehow oversaw that comment :)

Comment: Jon - Don't your two examples work for different reasons, the first because string derives from Object, and the second because namespace defines a conversion from string...or is this all the same under the hood?

Comment: @saurabh - I don't let it bring you down, MS is not the only place of work.  Take it as a learning experience and a way to move on.  Maybe it was for the better :).

Comment: @JonH : Yup , i moved on now and trying to refresh my concepts once more. :) thanks.

Comment: All this time, I've never really questioned this.  I've learned something today, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Because they're not the same type, if you define a TypeConverter then that would work.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx

Comment: haha, thanks Steven, glad to see you're still obsessed, you pathetic freak.

Answer (score 2):

Reference types are not assignable unless they are of the exact same type (this is known as type safety).  The first example works because you are assigning a string literal to a variable of the type `System.String`.  The second example does not work because you are assigning a string literal to a variable of the type `Employee`.  The types must match or be assignable from right to left for value assignment to work.

Comment: Same type or subtype. You can assign an DeveloperEmployee to an Employee (if DeveloperEmployee inherits from Employee).

Comment: Right - that is what I meant by assignable.

Comment: why are you stating "reference types are not assignable unless of the same type"? Type safety rules are the same for value types so why confuse the confused even more?

Answer (score 2):

```
Employee e = "Saurabh";
```

will not work simply because they are of different types.

Comment: Add an implicit operator to Employee and this will work.
Assume that Employee has a constructor that takes a string parameter:

public static implicit operator Employee(string name)
{
  return new Employee(name);
}

Answer (score 2):

```
object x;

x = new Employee();

x = "Hello World!";
```