# We just create a reference of string class without making a object of it and start using it, how is it possible?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, string

```
String s = "test";
```

String is a class, so to use it we should create an object of it. But rather we just make a reference of it and give it a value. How is it possible and what concepts are used in it.

The metadata of String class shows the following :

```
public sealed class String : IComparable, ICloneable, IConvertible, 
IComparable<string>, IEnumerable<char>, IEnumerable, IEquatable<string> {...}
```

Kindly explain. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see following post at SO

[Why string is a reference type, but behaves differently from other reference types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455274/why-string-is-a-reference-type)

Comment: Thanks Saurabh. It was the exact thing i was looking for ... this question was asked me in NIIT.